# Sqlalchemy: use PSQL's `~` operator when string is on left and column on right

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know that

```
WHERE column ~ 'regexp'
```

is this is sqlalchemy:

```
where(column.op('~')('regexp'))
```

but how could I create this?

```
WHERE 'string' ~ column
```

(the regex is stored in the database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create either a [`literal()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) or a [`bindparam()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

expression.literal('string').op('~')(column)
# or
expression.bindparam('text', 'string').op('~')(column)
```

A `literal()` is basically a `bindparam()` with an implicit name; in the above example `'text'` is the name (key) of the parameter as used in the SQL statement, and `'string'` the text you want to appear on the left-hand side of the operator.

A `bindparam()` gives you a bit more control, including the ability to pass in a *calleble* instead of a concrete value:

```
def value_function():
    return some_calculation_result()

expression.bindparam('calculated_value', callable_=value_function).op('~')(column)
```

and SQLAlchemy will call `value_function()` when sending the statement to the database server. You'd also use `bindparam()` if you have a *sequence* of values, and SQLAlchemy will take care of adjusting the expression to apply to each value in the sequence:

```
strings = ['string1', 'string2', ...]
expression.bindparam('one_or_more', strings).op('~')(column)
# executes `('string1' ~ column OR 'string2' ~ column OR ...)`
```

Comment: `literal('string')` can also be used in place of named `bindparam()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: indeed, and I can't quite find why I didn't mention that in 2013, it was already available in the prevalent SQLAlchemy versions of the time.

Answer (score 0):

An non-Sqlalchemy-specific solution would be to create your own operator in the PostgreSQL backend that has the operands reversed.  That would also allow you to do things like

```
string ### ANY(ARRAY[regexp1, regexp2, ...])
```

where `###` is your operator.  (Finding a good name might be a challenge.)